# Is there any option to set order for menu items in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, menu

How to set sort order for the below button items (ignore and pin) ? Its not showing in the exact sort order in the menu list. I think os itself is updating the sort order. is there any option to restrict the same?

struct ContentView: View {

```
var body: some View {
    Menu {
            Button(action: {
    self.self.placeOrder()
}) {
    HStack {
        Text("Ignore")
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        Image("Menu_Ignore")
            .renderingMode(.original)
    }
}

Button(action: {
    self.adjustOrder()
}) {
    HStack {
        Text("Pin")
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        Image("Menu_Pin")
            .renderingMode(.original)
    }
}
    } label: {
        Label("Options", systemImage: "paperplane")
    }
}

func placeOrder() { }
func adjustOrder() { }}
```

Answer (score 15):

### New in Xcode 14 / iOS 16 / macOS 13 / ...

Now we have environment value to manage this:

```
var body: some View {
    Menu {
       // .. buttons here
    }
    .environment(\.menuOrder, .fixed)     // << here !!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Update

As mentioned by Asperi, it's possible in iOS 16 & macOS 13
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/menuorder(_:)

### Original answer for iOS 15 & macOS 12 and lower

Your code is totally fine and it works perfectly. The problem you have probably relates to the fact that the first menu item will always appear closest to the `View` that the user tapped on to trigger the `Menu`. ("`Menu` label" in your example).

So if the tapped object is low on the screen, then the system might show the menu *above* instead of below the tap. When it does this, it reverses the order.

This might be not clear with 2 `Menu` items (because if you reverse them it might look as a random change of the order) but if you add more you'll see that the order stays the same but the whole `Menu` might be shown either below the tap with the normal order or above the tap with the reversed order.

Comment: As you mentioned "if you add more you'll see that the order stays the same but the whole Menu might be shown either from below with the normal order or above with the reversed order" , this is the issue I am facing. is there any option to keep the order same in all the conditions (without reverse order).

Comment: unfortunately no afaik. you see, the OS thinks: the order of the elements you provided is the priority order and therefore the first item should be the closest to the object you tap on. and respectively the last element - the least important - should be the farthest

Comment: It will be helpful if can give answer for one more question related with menu. Is there any option to set font for this menu items. It's not accepting custom font. Its showing with default system font (from phone settings).     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67120555/is-there-any-option-to-set-font-for-menu-items-in-swiftui

Comment: @Joby cannot answer that question unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

It feels like a force, but I solved it by getting the global y position of Menu with GeometryReader and setting the order at the top or bottom of the screen.

The position where you tapped the Menu (top or bottom) determines the order of the elements in the Menu, so I used that characteristic.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Menu("show menu") {
                    // get global position
                    let frame = geometry.frame(in: .global)
                    // top or bottom
                    let isTop = frame.midY <= UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2
                    if isTop {
                        Button("first button", action: {})
                        Button("second button", action: {})
                    }
                    else {
                        Button("second button", action: {})
                        Button("first button", action: {})
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 800)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```